# Is it OK for users to be able to open template files directly?

Tags: php, templates

I have a folder with PHP template files in (like `header.php`, and I call them from my scripts).

I know I can use something like `define('IN_APP', true)` and then in the template files use `if (!defined('IN_APP')) { exit; }` so if people browse these template files directly, they just get a blank page (or error message if you prefer).

Yes it will look strange seeing just a bit of unformatted data and some "undefined variable" errors, but the users would have to go out of their way to manually view these files, so is it really a problem?

Is it worth defining `IN_APP` and checking if it's defined every time a template file is called? Seems like a waste of processing power (even if it is almost unnoticeable)

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to put these files above the root directory. So you may want to create a dir structure like:

```
includes
   - templates
wwwroot
   - index.php
   - images
```

In this case users will not have access to anything under `includes`.